# How to change the package version in candidate?

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc, cuda

The output of command `apt-cache policy` as shown:

```
mobeen@VIP-Ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy gcc
gcc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages


mobeen@VIP-Ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy g++
    g++:
      Installed: (none)
      Candidate: 4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1
      Version table:
         4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1 500
            500 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
```

To my understanding this gives information about some package, that which version is installed and in the candidate, it means which version is going to be installed.

What I want to do is basically installed CUDA 8.0, which automatically installs gcc, but because of candidate version of gcc is 7.2.0, it installs this version. However, this afterwards gives compatibility errors.

In summary: I need to install a gcc version less than 5.

I am trying to install `torch` using the method described here: [link](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_).

The error I get is:

```
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mobeen/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:665: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mobeen/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:476: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mobeen/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:286: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mobeen/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:2027: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:172: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

I have installed `gcc-4.8` using the command:

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
```

and then symlinked it by using the command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.8 /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++
sudo ldconfig
```

But still get the same error.

Comment: This solved my problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103299/3360051)

Answer (score 1):

In the Ubuntu package system, `gcc` is a dependency package providing the *default* GNU C compiler.

If you want a non-default compiler version, you can install it explicitly - for example gcc-4.8 is [available on artful](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/gcc-4.8). You will need to enable the `universe` repository in your package sources.

You will likely need to take other steps to make CUDA find the correct versions - for example, creating a `/usr/local/cuda/bin` directory and symbolically linking `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` to `/usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc`

Comment: I followed your method, but still I get error when I try to build torch using the method described here: [link](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_). I have updated the question for the error I get while building torch.

Comment: Please re-check the link command you used - it should be `ln` not `ld`, and the target should be `/usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc` not `/usr/local/cuda/gcc/bin`. If your code uses `g++` you will need to repeat the process for `g++-4.8`. See for example [CUDA incompatible with my gcc version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version)

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned, I mistype here. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

> In summary: I need to install a gcc version less than 5.

GCC 4.8.5 is available in 17.10 from the package `gcc-4`.